# jQuery - Countdown360 plugin on every Monday with specific time

Tags: jquery, html5-canvas, jquery-countdown

I am using "[Countdown360](http://www.jqueryscript.net/time-clock/Simple-jQuery-Html5-Based-360-Degree-Countdown-Timer-countdown360.html)" jQuery plugin for scheduled events.

And it has been set to 100seconds from the page opens.

How can I configure the same in such a way that, This timer should run every **Monday** from **9am** to **9:01am**?

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/xzs7y03a/).

Is there any better plugin for this purpose?

```js
$("#countdown").countdown360({
  radius      : 80,
  seconds     : 60,
  fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
  autostart   : false,
  onComplete  : function () { console.log('done') }
}).start()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Html5-Based-360-Degree-Countdown-Timer-countdown360/src/jquery.countdown360.js"></script>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can't execute your script at the specific time, you've to check the time each second...

Here an example with parametrable day and time

> day number 1 => Monday

```js
function checkTime(dayok,hoursok,minuteok,secondsok)
{
  var date=new Date();
  var day = date.getDay();
  var hours  = date.getHours();
  var min = date.getMinutes();
  var seconds = date.getSeconds();
  console.log(day+ " - "+hours+":"+min+":"+seconds);
  if(day==dayok && hours==hoursok && minute==minuteok && seconds==secondsok)
    return true;
  else
    return false;
}

function goCountDown()
{
  if(checkTime(1,9,0,0))
  {
    $("#countdown").countdown360({
      radius      : 80,
      seconds     : 60,
      fontColor   : '#FFFFFF',
      autostart   : false,
      onComplete  : function () { console.log('done') }
    }).start()
  }
}

setInterval(function(){ goCountDown() }, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://www.jqueryscript.net/demo/Simple-jQuery-Html5-Based-360-Degree-Countdown-Timer-countdown360/src/jquery.countdown360.js"></script>

<div id="countdown"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer... I am Accepting and Upvoting your answer... Thanks for your time...